# bash: docker: command not found

Tags: server, bash, ssh, snap, docker

I'm accessing Ubuntu 19.10 running as a virtual machine. In the installation process I installed Docker (as a snap). Everything is fine when I log in using SSH, but this will fail:

`$ ssh user@host 'docker info'`

returning: `bash: docker: command not found`. Other commands like `$ ssh user@host date` or `$ ssh user@host 'ls -l'` woks fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried ssh user@host '/snap/bin/docker info'?

Comment: Thanks @Lutz. That works! So, I'm missing a link somewhere? Would be nice if I could just write 'docker'.

Comment: Yes the link is that snap installs everything in `/snap` and if you just ssh into the server this is not part of the environment variable `PATH`. This variable is used for searching executable files, if no path is given(e.g. calling `docker` vs `/snap/sbin/docker`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/docker /usr/bin/docker
```

You could also check what your path variable shows using the same command, but instead of `ls -l` use `echo $PATH` command. You could try to place symlinks to PATH mentioned there.

> Set the `PATH` on the server in `~/.ssh/environment` (needs to be enabled by `PermitUserEnvironment yes` in `sshd_config`).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332532/341457